# Need to write part of a python script that save data and writes it to a file

Tags: python, qt

I am currently using python and qt designer as a way of acquiring concentration values from a colorimeter. My current GUI has three buttons, "Connect", "Calibrate" and "Measure". Whenever I get to the measure part, it displays only one concentration value. If you were to place another sample in the colorimeter, it would delete the previous value and replace it with a new one.

When I write to a file, I am only able to save the last sample I measured, but I want to be able to log every one of the measurements.

This is currently what I have written for this particular part:

```
def measureSample(self):
    sys.stdout.flush()
    freqD1, trandD1, absoD1 = dev.getMeasurement(LED_TO_COLOR='D1'])
    freqD2, trandD2, absoD2 = dev.getMeasurement(LED_TO_COLOR='D2'])
    absoDiff= absoD1 - absoD2
    Coeff= 1 
    Conc = absoDiff/Coeff
    Conc3SD = '{Value:1.{digits}f'.format(Value = Conc, digits=3)
    self.textEdit.clear()
    self.textEdit.setText('Concentration is {0}.format(Conc3SD))

    timeStr = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S %Z')
    outFile = open('ConcentrationData.txt','w')
    outFile.write('{0} || Concentration: {1}'.format(timeStr, Conc3SD))
    outFile.close
```

So, my question is, how can I keep a log of every concentration value I take without it appearing on my GUI, AND how can I write them to a file? It's very important that I only display one value, not a list of the previous values on the GUI.

Thanks in advance!

-Marina

Comment: I am surprised it works at all as you don't call close. Use  `a` to append data to the file. `w` overwrites

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: you should use `with open('ConcentrationData.txt','a') as out_file: out_file.write..` and it will close it for you. You are missing `()` from close so you don't ever actually call it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham -- thank you! Just another quick question. The way it's set right now with it appending, that just means that it adds on to whatever previous data was on there beforehand. How could I make it such that you write over the previous file and then append the new data you measure?

Comment: Then just use `w` to overwrite as you are.

Comment: making sure you use with or close your file properly

Comment: Well, the problem I was having whenever I set it to "w" is that it only showed one value in the text file, even though when I had the program running I would measure 10 samples. I wanted it append the samples I would measure when the program was running, but if I were to close it and open it again, I would want the previous samples to be written over, if that makes sense? So, setting it to "w" doesn't help me with this particular problem and neither does setting it to "a".

Comment: you need to open outside the method at the very start of your code each time for each run using `w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick lies in the `'w'` in your `open()` call.  This means you want to write a new file.  Change it to `'a'` for appending to an existing file.  See here for more info: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open

Also, you may find it helpful to note that the literal string character of `\n` will make a new line in a file (and if you want Windows-style new lines, you want `\r\n` - without that, opening in something like Notepad won't show you the new lines)

Comment: Thank you! I will try that out, but I think that should work perfectly!

Comment: No problem!  As Padraic commented, you might also want to close the file, to guarantee that everything is written out before your program terminates.  Also, if I answered your question, please accept the answer!  It helps me out with reputation on the site.

Comment: Also, when I change it to append the file, I want to be able to write over what was there previously and then append the new data. How can I do that?

Comment: So, if you want to do that, I think the best way would be to open the file in write mode, like you initially did, write repeatedly, and then close.  This means you'll have to restructure where you open and close your file a bit.